# Custom Compare function for std::binary_search

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

Is there any problem with this code?

```
bool Spellcheck::smart_comp(string value, string key){
    return true;
}

void func(){
    std::string aprox_key = "hello";
    if(std::binary_search(this->words.begin(), this->words.end(), aprox_key, smart_comp)){
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I am trying to write my own compare function for comparing strings in binarysearch

I am getting following error:

```
xyz.cpp:40:85: error: no matching function for call to ‘binary_search(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::string&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
xyz.cpp:40:85: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2665:5: note: template<class _FIter, class _Tp> bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2698:5: note: bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _Compare = bool (Spellcheck::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2698:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘bool (Spellcheck::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)’
```

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any problem with this code?
>
> ```
> bool Spellcheck::smart_comp(string const value, string const key){
>   return true;
> }
> ```

Other than it always returns `true`? Yes, the basic problem is that a member function has an implicit parameter `this`, so the signature does not match that of the expected predicate. You should be doing this function `static` or even a free function (`friend`ed if needed). Also you are copying the `strings` each time, it would be best if you take the arguments by const reference to avoid unneeded copies.

In case the real result of the predicate depends on the state of the `Spellcheck` object, you will have to bind that state to the member function in order to create a function object with the appropiate signature:

```
std::binary_search(
    this->words.begin(), this->words.end()
  , std::bind( &Spellcheck::smart_comp, this )
);
```

Comment: You mean to say, I have to put this function outside the class?

Comment: @Ringo: Indeed, if it does not depend on the object contents. Otherwise you need a function object to carry such state.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass a non-static member function, which is not convertible to the required binary function (on account of having *three* actual parameters).

Try declaring your `smart_comp` function `static`. (Of course then you can't refer to instance members; if you need statefulness, you'll have to write a full functor.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this->words`'s type is `std::vector<std::string>` and `func` is a member of `Spellcheck`, you can work it around declaring `smart_comp` to be `static`. But I would think twice on your class design.

Comment: why do you think my class design is flawed? Well I agree on the other point

Comment: @Ringo : Because there's no apparent reason to put the comparison logic inside of any class other than a stateful functor.